# Как обновить только один атрибут для пользователя?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

есть пользователь с такими атрибутами:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "default"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end
```

Есть профиль пользователя, где он может добавить себе аватар. Вот форма для этого:

```
  <%= form_for @user do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group is-empty is-fileinput">
      <label class="col-md-3  control-label">Choose your avatar</label>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse...">
        <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
      </div>
      <span class="material-input"></span>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
           <%= form.submit "Update user avatar", class:"btn btn-raised btn-danger m20" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  <% end %>
```

Контроллер

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "User profile was successufly updated"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
      puts "------------"
      puts @user.avatar_file_name.nil?
   else

   end
 end

  private
    def user_params
       params.require(:user_params).permit(:avatar)
    end

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Но сейчас при нажатии на submit ошибка param is missing or the value is empty: user_params. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправить нужные параметры, или возможно есть другой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так в `@user` лежит объект класса `User`. Рискну предположить, что на форме у инпута для аватара в аттрибуте `name` лежит что-то типа `user[avatar]`. А значит и в контроллере в `params` попадает что-то типа

```
{ user: { avatar: #<TempFile:...> } }
```

А в `user_params` ты требуешь чтобы был ключ `:user_params`.

Варианта решения два:

Либо исправить параметры хэлпера для генерации формы

```
<%= form_for @user, as: :user_params do |form| %>
```

Либо исправить `require`:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
```

Имхо, второй вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: Спасибо, невнимательность меня погубит)

Comment: Да, все работает)

Comment: @D-side, странно, был уверен, что должно работать именно так, как я написал. Но сейчас открыл доки и они со мной не согласны. Исправил. Спасибо.